# Como Exibir consulta com inner join em mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho essas duas tabelas e gostaria de consultar os proprietarios de acordo com o tipo das propriedades que tem o id_proprietario.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que eu tentei fazer foi isso:

```
select
    *
from
    proprietario
inner join
    propriedade
on proprietario.id_agente = propriedade.proprietario 
where propriedade.tipo = "Terreno" and exibicao = "Externo" 
 and proprietario.id_agente = "1"
```

Com isso eu seleciono todos os que se encaixam no filtro, mas não sei como exibir os proprietarios desta lista sem repetir, apenas uma vez.

Se o banco estiver errado eu posso alterar também, se puderem me ajudar.

Comment: só colocar `distinct`: `select distinct * from proprietario inner join propriedade on proprietario.id_agente = propriedade.proprietario where propriedade.tipo = "Terreno" and exibicao = "Externo" and proprietario.id_agente = "1"`

Comment: Como condição de junção você quer realmente comparar um int(11) (proprietario.id_agente) com um varchar(1000) (propriedade.proprietario)? Pesquise sobre chave estrangeira.

Comment: erro meu o proprietario.proprietario era para ser um init tambem servindo como chave estrangeira

Comment: como funciona o distinct? sabe me dizer vou pesquisar melhor para entender.

Answer (score 0):

Para melhor entendimento, caso você executar a segunte instrução:

```
select distinct(id_agente) from proprietario
```

você estará evitando que algum proprietário se repita na consulta, pelo id do agente na tabela.

No meu ponto de vista, alteraria o campo "proprietário" da tabela propriedade, para id_proprietario com chave estrangeira para a tabela de proprietário, campo "id_agente".

Assim você tem um relacionamento entre as tabelas e sua consulta - independente de condição where tipo, agente e exibição - ficará mais simplificada. Podendo ser executado o seguinte código:

```
select distinct(p1.id_agente) from proprietario p1 
inner join propriedade p2 on p1.id_agente=p2.id_proprietario
```

Comment: entendi, vou fazer essas alterações, obrigado.

Comment: Utilizei estas instruções e deu certo, funcionou perfeitamente, fico muito grato pela ajuda.